# Creating new variable based on reference date calculation

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple participants (distinguished by the variable "ID") and calendar dates (MM/DD/YYYY) associated with each row of data.

I would like to create a "Day" column to calculate the number of days that has elapsed since the first calendar date for each ID (i.e. using the first date for each participant as a reference date).

Example Structure:

```
ID Calendar.date Day
 1    06/23/2020   1
 1    06/25/2020   3
 1    06/26/2020   4
 2    03/24/2019   1
 2    03/30/2019   7
 2    03/31/2019   8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` approach. If you `group_by` the ID, you can subtract dates from the `first` date for each ID. This assumes you have your data in a data frame `df`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Calendar_date = as.Date(Calendar_date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
         Day = Calendar_date - first(Calendar_date) + 1)
```

For the output below, I modified your example data to avoid impossible dates in February. Also, the result for `Day` is a `difftime` object. If you simply want the numeric number of days just use `as.numeric`:

```
as.numeric(Calendar_date - first(Calendar_date))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID Calendar_date Day   
  <dbl> <date>        <drtn>
1     1 2020-06-23    1 days
2     1 2020-06-25    3 days
3     1 2020-06-26    4 days
4     2 2019-02-20    1 days
5     2 2019-02-26    7 days
6     2 2019-02-27    8 days
```